# How to make function and loop in VUE correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to write in VUE as well as js or jquery but this framework have some secrets i do not discover yet. I want to make simple loop for and function but i can just make the simplest calculation.
I write somethink like that and this calculator work perfect:

```
data: {
    pv: {
      p: '',
      pd: '', 
      d: '',
      u: '',
      w: '',
    
   },
  },
  methods: {
    calc: function () {
    var d = this.pv.d
    var p = this.pv.p
    var u = this.pv.u
        var w = this.pv.w
  this.pv.pd = p - d; 
this.pv.w =  this.pv.pd - u;

},
```

but i want to have something more advance:

```
this.pv.w = function(){if(w < 1000){return 1000-u;}else{w-u;}}
```

in simple js it would work perfect but i do not understand VUE framework as well. Or a loop for

`this.pv.w = function(){for(i=0;i<10;i++){var s = u*i;}}`

This is easy task i do not find in their documentation

`just find that loop is {{n in 50}}` but i want have calculation od "js side" then put in to html dom if i want to.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints on how to use the variables in vue:

```
  data() return {
    pv: {
      p: '',
      pd: '', 
      d: '',
      u: '',
      w: '',
   },
  },
  methods: {
    calc1() {  // no function keyword required
      let pv = this.pv;  // shorthand
      pv.d = pv.p - pv.d; 
      pv.w =  pv.pd - pv.u;
    },
    calc2() {
      let pv = this.pv;
      if(pv.w < 1000){
        pv.w = 1000 - pv.u;
      } else {
        pv.w = pv.w - pv.u;
      }
    },
    calc3() {
      let pv = this.pv;
      for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
        pv.w += pv.u*i;
      }
    }
```